# Upgrade install from EE2 to EE3?

Tags: upgrade

Do I need to have the latest version of EE2 installed before upgrading to EE3?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EE Recommends that you're on 2.10.1, this way you're less likely to run into issues. You'll want to make sure you have EE3 compatible plugins.  The EE3 upgrade process requires you to change a lot of your EE2 files/directories to adhere to the new EE3 standards.

https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/installation/upgrade_from_2.x.html

**Edited for clarity thanks to user1070143.**

Comment: Many thanks you the reply. I've read the page you linked me to, but there is no mention of needing to use the latest version of EE2 before upgrading to EE3. Ah! Read your answer again... so I don't need to have the latest version of EE2 installed before upgrading to EE3. Thank you!

Comment: From EE officially: For the best upgrade results we do recommend having at least 2.10.1 installed before moving to version 3.

Comment: Can't argue with that.  I guess I should have expanded my answer to say that it would be ideal to be more up to date so you have less of a chance of running into issues.